# PHP generate rgb color to object based on unique value

Tags: php, algorithm, function, math, colors

I know this has been asked before, but I need a little more help than the other answers on SO provide.

I currently have a foreach loop that iterates over records in my DB. Each row contains a unique "id" primary attribute (1,2,3,4,5,etc.).

In my loop, I need to generate a UNIQUE RGB value for each record based on its ID. The resulting RGB value will be applied to the HTML element's text bound to that record. The generated color must be unique to the record itself (via "id"), which is why I am not using the loop iterator.

I have already created a working function to do this for me, but I need one more thing - I need the rgb value to have a contrast ratio greater than 4:5:1 on a white background. The function I have generates colors that are too bright, making the text hard to read. How can I modify my function to produce darker colors that contrast well on a white background?

```
function makeRgbFromValue(int $value){
    $hash = md5($value);

    return implode(", ", [
        hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 2)), // r
        hexdec(substr($hash, 2, 2)), // g
        hexdec(substr($hash, 4, 2))  // b
    ]);
}

// Example output: "100, 201, 20"

// My html, using Laravel Blade syntax:

@foreach($categories as $cat)
    <a 
        href="/blog/channels/{{ $cat->slug }}"
        style="color: rgb(
           {{ makeRgbFromValue($cat->id) }}
        )"
    >
        {{ $cat->name }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

Maybe this isnt possible... but I'm hoping one of you Math geniuses can help me out :)

Comment: by using md5, your incrementing value will collide at some point so you cant guarantee unique..

Comment: How will it collide if he uses a unique ID every time? @LawrenceCherone

Comment: It dont have to be 100% unique, but I prefer less collisions than more. md5 is suitable for now

Comment: Why not defining let's say 50 or 100 colors manually and loop them through the records? Id 1 get color 1, id 2 get color 2 and id 101 get color 1 again. It would give you more control about the output

Comment: I would like you to think about this from a UX point of view. Human perception can only reasonably distinguish a limited number of colors (some people say up to 7 +- 2). So, it might be more reasonable and easier to pre-specify a color palette (e.g. from [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/)) and pick the color from that based on the id.

Comment: @Ice76 Because substr the first 6 chars destroys the entropy.. https://3v4l.org/j9fve thats with just 100k iterations

Comment: @NicoSchertler so if I have an array of 8 rgb values $colors, how would I pick a color from that array based on the respective id? if there is an id of 12, then I cant say $colors[12] because the keys are only 0-7. how do I approach this? again, I am OK with repeating colors

Comment: Just use `$colors[id % 8]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate brightness:

```
function lumdiff($R1,$G1,$B1,$R2,$G2,$B2){
    $L1 = 0.2126 * pow($R1/255, 2.2) +
          0.7152 * pow($G1/255, 2.2) +
          0.0722 * pow($B1/255, 2.2);

    $L2 = 0.2126 * pow($R2/255, 2.2) +
          0.7152 * pow($G2/255, 2.2) +
          0.0722 * pow($B2/255, 2.2);

    if($L1 > $L2){
        return ($L1+0.05) / ($L2+0.05);
    }else{
        return ($L2+0.05) / ($L1+0.05);
    }
}
```

The returned value should be bigger than 5 for best readability.
Function was found [here](https://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-09/18-calculating_color_contrast_with_php)

But you should get another chars from a hash to get another color, so collision more probable.

```
function makeRgbFromValue($value){
    $hash = md5($value);
    $brightness = 0;
    $shift = 0;

    while($brightness < 5 && $shift<26) {
        $color = [
            hexdec(substr($hash, $shift, 2)), // r
            hexdec(substr($hash, $shift+2, 2)), // g
            hexdec(substr($hash, $shift+4, 2))  // b
        ];
        $brightness = lumdiff($color[0], $color[1], $color[2], 255,255,255);
        $shift++;
    }

    return implode(", ", $color);
}
```

I believe that a color will be found in 25 cycles :)

Comment: thanks, I already tried this exact thing by repeating the function until the brightness is "ok", but in some cases the loop could take forever if it doesnt generate a good enough color the first few tries.

Comment: @amcardwell added a function with a while loop. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

While it's a pain to translate, HSV is probably a better color space for this. I like to pick a set Saturation [0.75 is nice] and then play with the Hue and Value.

Lifting the HSV/RGB conversion function from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zyphlar/55dea0fae7914ff8eb4a):

```
function HSV_TO_RGB ($H, $S, $V) {
    $RGB = array(); 
    if($S == 0) { 
        $R = $G = $B = $V * 255; 
    } else { 
        $var_H = $H * 6; 
        $var_i = floor( $var_H ); 
        $var_1 = $V * ( 1 - $S ); 
        $var_2 = $V * ( 1 - $S * ( $var_H - $var_i ) ); 
        $var_3 = $V * ( 1 - $S * (1 - ( $var_H - $var_i ) ) ); 
        if       ($var_i == 0) { $var_R = $V     ; $var_G = $var_3  ; $var_B = $var_1 ; } 
        else if  ($var_i == 1) { $var_R = $var_2 ; $var_G = $V      ; $var_B = $var_1 ; } 
        else if  ($var_i == 2) { $var_R = $var_1 ; $var_G = $V      ; $var_B = $var_3 ; } 
        else if  ($var_i == 3) { $var_R = $var_1 ; $var_G = $var_2  ; $var_B = $V     ; } 
        else if  ($var_i == 4) { $var_R = $var_3 ; $var_G = $var_1  ; $var_B = $V     ; } 
        else                   { $var_R = $V     ; $var_G = $var_1  ; $var_B = $var_2 ; } 
        $R = $var_R * 255; 
        $G = $var_G * 255; 
        $B = $var_B * 255; 
    } 
    $RGB['R'] = $R; 
    $RGB['G'] = $G; 
    $RGB['B'] = $B; 
    return $RGB; 
}
```

And then:

```
$fmt = '<span style="background-color: #%s" title="%s">%s</span>' . "\n";
$fill = str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);

$S = 0.75;
for($i=0; $i<25; $i++) {
    $hash = md5(mt_rand());
    $H =   hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 2))/255;
    $V = ( hexdec(substr($hash, 2, 2))/255 ) / 2 + 0.5; // pick from the brighter half
    $rgb = implode('', array_map(
    function($a){
        return str_pad(dechex(intval($a)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }, HSV_TO_RGB($H, $S, $V)));
    printf($fmt, $rgb, sprintf("HSV(%0.2f,%0.2f,%0.2f)", $H, $S, $V), $fill);
}
```

Gives us something like:

[image: yay colored boxes!]